# Android build path entries are missing

Tags: java, android, adt

In my eclipse ide -> java build path says two build path entries are missing. How should i add the build path entries. Please refer the attached image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In properties window, go to Resource tab and make sure the PATH of both dependences are correct (if not, you'll see a red cross like the one you display on the image)